# Is it possible to make a O((n!)!) complexity algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, factorial

I can't imagine how such an algorithm would be constructed.

Would the algorithm "for every permutation of N elements, brute-force the traveling salesman problem, where the edges are decided by the order of the elements" have such a complexity?

Comment: The "algorithm" doesn't have to _do anything_ except count to (n!)!. So of course this is possible.

Comment: @nneonneo You should post that as an answer. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef: Hehe, OK. Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your algorithm!

```
import math

def eat_cpu(n):
    count = 0
    for _ in xrange(math.factorial(math.factorial(n))):
        count += 1
    return count

eat_cpu(4)
```

It is a function that calculates (n!)! using the *method of incrementation*. It takes O((n!)!) time.

---

Actually, upon reflection, I realized that this algorithm is also O((n!)!):

```
def dont_eat_cpu(n):
    return 0
```

because O is an *upper* bound. We commonly forget this when throwing O(...) around. The previous algorithm is thus Theta((n!)!) in addition to being O((n!)!), while this one is just Theta(1).

Comment: +1, I especially like the second part of your answer. It's important to keep reminding people about the caveats of Big-Oh. Here's another one: `def f(n): return 0 if n <= 10**(10**10) else eat_cpu(n)` is Theta((n!)!) albeit being completely practical for a lot of imaginable values of *n*. To be fair, this kind situation doesn't often occur for real algorithms :)

Comment: Indeed, I didn't quite know the meaning of O(...).

Comment: It would be interesting to see _natural_ problem with the best-known algorithm of time complexity O((n!)!), or a lower bound of O((n!)!) for the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Enumerating all partitions of a set is `O(n!)`. Now, all permutations of all partitions of a set will be `O((n!)!)`, although the example is a bit artificial. Now, to come up with a useful algorithm it's a totally different story. I am not aware of any such algorithm, and in any case its scaling will be absolutely awful.

Comment: To illustrate: (2!)! = 2, (3!)! = 720, (4!)! = 620448401733239439360000, (5!)! = 6689502913449127057588118054090372586752746333138029810295671352301633557244962989366874165271984981308157637893214090552534408589408121859898481114389650005964960521256960000000000000000000000000000. So yes, any such algorithm would be beyond impractical.

Answer (score 1):

You can do better than that - there are known to be problems that require 2^2^(p(n)) time to solve - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-EXPTIME - and it appears that these problems are not completely artificial either: "Generalizations of many fully observable games are EXPTIME-complete"